# Laravel: queue work failed pcntl_signal() for security

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-artisan

trying to run `php artisan queue:work` returns this error:

```
ErrorException  : pcntl_signal() has been disabled for security reasons
```

Already removed `pcntl_signal, pcntl_signal_dispatch` from disable_functions in php.ini and restart, but no effect
[image: curity]

Comment: Any news about this one?

Comment: @MattKenefick did you manage to solve the problem? I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Just some information about a situation that occurred for myself.

- Laravel will call pcntl methods if the extension is enabled.
- Even if pcntl extension is enabled, the function may be blacklisted in your php.ini file specifically using the disable_functions option.
- In this case, Laravel's check for the extension will pass but the call to the method will then fail with a similar error message due to the function being disabled.
- An update to php.ini to disable the extension or remove the functions from the blacklist should solve the problem in this case.

From what I can tell, it's common practice to disable the functions introduced by the pcntl extension, though I'm not sure of the history around why this is.

Edit: A follow up to this is that pcntl can be built into PHP and not necessarily an extension. In this case, you must remove the functions from the disabled_functions configuration to resolve the pcntl call, or rebuild PHP without pcntl.